# How to exclude numbers (which have '/') in alphanumeric variable

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I'm struggling on how can I remove everything after numbers with "/", for example, I have the following vector

```
x <-c("Rua 12 de outubro", "Outubro 1/900", "Rua A 4/2 outracoisa", "Rua a 2")
```

and I'd like to obtain

```
x <-c("Rua 12 de outubro", "Outubro", "Rua A", "Rua a 2")
```

i.e., exclude the number with "/" and everyting after them.

I tried to use `gsub` without success. Any int on how can I do that?

Comment: Please share the code you tried to see what issue you are having.

Comment: someone comment the rigth answer and excluded. The answer worked very well and solved my problem. Here is the answer: `sub("^([^/]+)\\<.*/.*", "\\1", x)`

Comment: No, the answer is simpler than that. What is *your* attempt? What is the programming issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming only one "/" in the string:

```
x <-c("Rua 12 de outubro", "Outubro 1/900", "Rua A 4/2 outracoisa", "Rua a 2")

sub("(.*) \\d+/\\d+.*", '\\1', x)
#[1] "Rua 12 de outubro" "Outubro"           "Rua A"             "Rua a 2"
```

Comment: `sub("\\s?\\d+/\\d+.*", "", x)`

Comment: and using the new string literals in R 4.0x - `sub(r"(\s?\d+/\d+.*)", "", x)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `sub` to carry out a substitution and divide the string into two capturing groups `(...)`: one before the `/`character that you want to keep and one after it that you want to discard. Then refer back to the first capturing group with `\\1` and replace the whole string with that group:

```
sub("(.+)(/.+)", "\\1", x)
[1] "Rua 12 de outubro" "Outubro 1"         "Rua A 4"           "Rua a 2"
```

Alternatively you can define the first capturing group via a negated character class `[^/]+`, which allows for any characters one or more times *except* the `/` character:

```
sub("([^/]+)(/.+)", "\\1", x)
```